# jqtranform not applied to dynamically added fields

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

I'm using the jqtransform for my form fields. When i added the dynamic field to the form, the jqtransform is not applied to new field.
Please see the samplecode,

```
$(function(){

$('form#js_greatdeals_form').jqTransform();


$('#js_greatdeals_form div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').click(function(){
var value = $(this).parent().index();
      $("#select_cntry").attr('selectedIndex', value);
      var countryiso = $("#select_cntry").val();

        if(countryiso == 1) {
        var content = '<select name="state" id="state"><option value="s1">State1</option><option value="s2">State2</option></select>';
        $('#newselect').html(content);
        $('select#state').jqTransform(); //Newly added
        }
    }); 
});
```

My form is,

```
<form id="js_greatdeals_form" name="js_greatdeals_form" method="post">
  <select id="select_cntry">
    <option selected="selected">select</option>
    <option value="1">Country1</option>
    <option value="2">Country2</option>
  </select>
  <div id="newselect"></div>
</form>
```

I tried the answer given for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468629/add-new-formelemts-and-transform-it-with-jqtransform) [Please see the comment line "Newly added"]. But that solution also not work for me. 
Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem, here is an answer that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900367/jqtransform-select-ajax-update/9392412

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900367/jqtransform-select-ajax-update/9392412

Answer (score 0):

open your jquery.jqtransform.js file and find the following line:

```
/* Fire the onchange event */
if ($select[0].selectedIndex != $(this).attr('index') && $select[0].onchange) {
    $select[0].selectedIndex = $(this).attr('index');
    $select[0].onchange();
 }
```

now simply add the following below that line:

```
/* Fire the change event */
 if ($select[0].selectedIndex != $(this).attr('index')) {
     $select[0].selectedIndex = $(this).attr('index');
    $($select[0]).trigger('change');
 }
```

Comment: the first set of rules might be overridding the second. try commenting out the first if statement.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I commented the first if statement. Still it is not working.

Comment: bah. comment it back in then. it's a piece of the original code so should probably stay there!

Comment: hey look at this http://blog.divdesigns.com/2010/02/dynamic-forms-with-jqtransform/  another hack!

Comment: in your jqtransform.js code. comment this line:

if($select.hasClass('jqTransformHidden')) {return;}

And then, after "onchange" event run:

$('#container select').jqTransSelect();

Comment: I tried all above solutions. But it does not provide the desired output.

Comment: sorry i could not be of more help. :(